# Spring boot notification on edit

Tags: java, spring-boot, push-notification

I currently have a simple service with two columns.

```
Userid, Party

1, 
2,
```

Both clients retrieve this object on startup, with an empty party.
One user can add some text in the Party column for both users. However when that happens, i would like to update the front end of both users.

How can i let user 1 know that party has been updated? Keep requesting the object for change would be bad practise.

Comment: You can use socket.io, but of course not an easy implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as said by Himadri Mandal, the proper way to do such thing would be to use websockets.

There is a clear tutorial on how to implement websocket using Spring available here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/